# Passing array of structs to function

Tags: c

An exercise at the end of chapter 10 of "Programming in C" by Stephen Kochan says to write a function that sorts an array of `structs` in alphabetical order.

The struct has the form

```
struct entry
{
    char word[15];
    char definition[50];
};
```

which mimics a dictionary. An array of these `structs` would look like this

```
const struct entry dictionary[10] =
{
    {"agar",        "a jelly made from seaweed"},
    ...,
    ...,
    {"aerie",       "a high nest"}
}
```

The definition of `struct entry` is global, `dictionary` is in main.

I wrote a function that is supposed to sort this dictionary alphabetically called dictionarySort

```
void dictionarySort(struct entry dictionary[], int entries)
```

with `entries` being the number of elements in `dictionary`. In `main` I declare the function and call it with

```
dictionarySort(dictionary, 10);
```

Now I get the errors

`warning: passing argument 1 of ‘dictionarySort’ discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]`

for the function call and

`note: expected ‘struct entry *’ but argument is of type ‘const struct entry *’
 void dictionarySort(struct entry dictionary[], int entries)`

for the function header.

I found [Passing an array of structs in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206014/passing-an-array-of-structs-in-c#8206173) and followed the accepted answer but it still does not work. Note that I have not learned about pointers as they have not been introduced in the book yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

juste drop the const in your array declaration.

for the compiler const mean that the memory space allocated on the stack for this variable is read-only, so your function should not modify it.

Comment: Note that this answer is not universal. It’s correct in this case, but in a lot of cases the correct answer is “add `const` to the function”. You should prefer that, if possible.

Comment: Would that not mean that I cannot change the passed argument within the function as the header defines it to be a `const`?