# In C:how to pass an array of data type structure in a function?

Tags: arrays, c, function, structure

How can I pass a whole array named `arrayt` of type structure named task to a function called `create_task`?

We need to define the data type of `arrayt` while passing it to a function. What would be its data type? task, struct task or struct?

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// problem: HOW TO PASS AN ARRAY IN A FUNCTION OF TYPE STRUCT
void create_task(struct task arrayt );

struct task{
    char t_name[99];
    char task_noted[999];
};

int main()
{
    struct task arrayt[999];
    int check=0;
    while(check>3||check<1){
        printf("Enter 1 to create a task\nEnter 2 to delete a task\nEnter 3 to view task:\n");
        scanf("%d",&check);
    }

    switch(check){
        case 1:
            printf("CREATING A TASK\n");
            create_task(arrayt);
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("DELETE TASK");
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("VEIW TASKS");
            break;
        default :
            printf("INVALID OPTION!!!!");
            break;
    }
}

void create_task(struct task arrayt ){
    char name ;
    printf("Enter Task Name: ");
    scanf(" %s ",&name);
    FILE *ptr;
    ptr = fopen("data.txt","a");
    
    fclose(ptr);
}
```

Comment: Change `void create_task(struct task arrayt);`  to `void create_task(struct task arrayt [] );`

Comment: Or simply `void create_task(struct task *arrayt )` An array-of-type is converted to pointer-to-type on access [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3)

Comment: [Error] array type has incomplete element type

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing an array of structs in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206014/passing-an-array-of-structs-in-c)

Comment: You don't use `&` with `"%s"` and `char name;` that is *Undefined Behavior*. There is no room for `'\0'`. You either use `"%c"` or you must declare `name` as an array of char and drop the `&`.

Comment: do we have to declare our structures before our functions?

Comment: i know there are alot of mistakes in my code because we have a really awful teacher and we have to make a project; and they haven't even completed the syllabus. AND THE DEADLINE IS NEXT WEEK!!!
im dead hahaha

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct task{
char t_name[99];
char task_noted[999];
};

void create_task(struct task arrayt[] ); // Function prototype after structure declaration    

int main(){

struct task arrayt[999];
int check=0;
while(check>3||check<1){
    printf("Enter 1 to create a task\nEnter 2 to delete a task\nEnter 3 to veiw task:\n");
    scanf("%d",&check);
}

switch(check){
    case 1:
        printf("CREATING A TASK\n");
        create_task(arrayt);
        break;
    case 2:
        printf("DELETE TASK");
        break;
    case 3:
        printf("VEIW TASKS");
        break;
    default :
        printf("INVALID OPTION!!!!");
        break;
}
}
void create_task(struct task arrayt[] ){
char name[50]; // defined an array
printf("Enter Task Name: ");
scanf(" %s",name);  // No need of &

// Do whaterever required here.
}
```