# Accessing the member of structure passed to a function as array of structure

Tags: c

I have a structure named book which is defined as:

```
struct book
{
char name[30];
};
```

I created an array of the structure in this manner:

```
  struct book b[2];
```

I passed it to a function and want to acess it like `b[i].name` since i am passing array i have to deal with pointer in my function .since i am using a for loop i wrote `ptr[i]->name` but that is not working.

I found a similar question at [Passing an array of structs in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206014/passing-an-array-of-structs-in-c) however that doesnot solve my problem.
My total program is:

```
#include<stdio.h>

 struct book
 {
   char name[30];
 };
void input(struct book [2]);
void display(struct book [2]);

 int main()
 {
 struct book b[2];
 struct book;
 input(b);
 display(b);
 }

void input(struct book *b1)
{
for (int i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++)
{
 printf("Enter the name of book\n");
 scanf(" %[^\n]s",b1[i]->name);
}

}
void display(struct book *b1)
{
 for (int i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++)
  {
 printf("Name of book: %s",b1[i]->name);
  }
 }
```

Comment: Why doesn't it resolve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The member can be accessed like the following, (the same fix for both `display()` and `input()` )

```
void display(struct book *b1)
{
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++)
    {
        printf("Name of book: %s",b1[i].name); // here
    }
 }
```

Comment: warning: passing argument 1 of 'input' from incompatible pointer type however code works well

Comment: you don't need to change the line `input(b)` actually. that should get rid of the warning.

Comment: @IcanCode - the code as shown here is correct and when used with remainder of your code as shown, should compile with no warnings.  (My answer was misleading, and now deleted.)